# Annotation Processing: how to change annotation target in Kotlin code?

Tags: java, kotlin, annotation-processing, kapt, kotlinc

Quite often, when I use annotations from Java libraries in Kotlin code, I have to specify target in order to specify what element in the compilled code has to be annotated:

```
data class User(
    val id: String,

    @get:Email
    val email: String
)
```

Instead of specifying `@get:Email`, I would love to be able to use simply `@Email`, especially if it occurs in many places.

**Question:** Is there a way to hint Kotlin compiler to use a different target in all places so that if I use `@Email` it will handle it as if it was `@get:Email`? Or is there any other way to omit specifying target? How can it be achieved? May it be done on the compilation stage via annotation processing (like [Lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok) does)?

I would appreciate any ideas even if they don't answer my question directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override it. Maybe create annotation that will target `@Email` annotation and provide the property getter when it tries to call target.

Specifying target is dictated by the annotation target. When the target of the annotation is specified to [jvm use-targets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) then you must use `@get:` to specify that the annotation targets the getter of the property.

In order to use simply `@Email` you must use kotlin [target types](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.annotation/-annotation-target/) for your annotation, probably `PROPERTY`. Note that, `PROPERTY` target doesn't work with Java.

```kotlin
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
annotation class Email
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible with Kotlin Compiler plugins API. It's a complicated way, tho.

To achieve this you will need to add a ClassBuilder interceptor with a visitor handling `@Email` annotation and specifying a correct target.

Can't say without getting deeper if visitor will be enough or you will also need to modify source code on one of the compiler stages, check TreeVisitor.